# spring JavaScript Promises callback function parameter

Tags: javascript, spring, promise

I guess this is a really basic question for promise, but just need someone to clarify to me. I am reading this documentation "[Understanding JavaScript Promises](https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises#understanding-javascript-promises)". In the example the code is as following

```
var greetingPromise = sayHello();
greetingPromise.then(function (greeting) {
    console.log(greeting);    // 'hello world’
}, function (error) {
    console.error('uh oh: ', error);   // 'uh oh: something bad happened’
});
```

What I am confused about are the parameters in the onSuccess and onError functions, named "greeting" and "error". What are they, or in the other world where are they defined? How shall I know what I am expecting to get from there? (maybe in the sayHello() function?)

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`greeting` is the value returned by the promised returned by `sayHello`. `error` is the error object for the error that may be caused during the execution of the promise.

A possible implementation of `sayHello` would be:

```
function sayHello(){
    return new Promise((res, rej) => res("hello world"));
}
```

As a clarification, they are not called `onSuccess` and `onError`, but you can indeed think of them as such. `greeting` is a `string`.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes so much sense now! Thank you.